# Wait x seconds or until sql query returns results

Tags: java, conditional-statements, countdownlatch

I'm trying to implement a method that continuously run a SQL query until it returns results or fails after x seconds.

Currently my method uses CountDownLatch:

```
final CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);

new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run() {
         try
        {
          getQueryResults(sql);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        done.countDown();
    }
}).start();

return done.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried Google? ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397432/can-i-set-a-jdbc-timeout-for-a-single-query