# Specify a query timeout for only a single query JDBCTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

So the scenario is I want to rollback if a particular query if it crosses a particular time threshold using JDBCTemplate in Spring boot. However I dont want to use the timeout function from JDBC class since it'll be reflected project wide for all db transactions. Also if the query does get executed a RowMapper needs to be invoked to map the ResultSet to an object. So is it possible to only enable it for a query? Most answers are using PreparedStatement but does that support RowMapper?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I set a JDBC timeout for a single query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397432/can-i-set-a-jdbc-timeout-for-a-single-query)

Comment: That doesnt solve my issue @birca123 since I also need a RowMapper if the query execution goes through